# How to make two servos work one after another? And stop shaking?

Tags: button, arduino, servo, piano, arduino-c++

For my project, I am trying to make a page-turner that's controlled by two servos --- one to flip (with a horn) and one to lift (with a wheel). My goal here is when I press the RIGHT button, my wheel should roll a page clockwise FIRST then my horn will swipe from left to right (the same but opposite for my LEFT button) to turn a page.

While I am trying to adjust the angles, I have my button right servo works the way I wanted to but it's shaking, on the other hand, I have my button right servo works smooth and continuously but the flip and the turn were both active at the same time.

```
#include <Servo.h>

const int swipservo = 8; //yellow
const int liftservo = 9; //green
Servo servo1;  // create servo object to control a servo
Servo servo2;
const int leftbutton = 11; //yellow = turn left
const int rightbutton = 12; //blue = turn right

int pos1 = 0;    // variable to store the servo position
int pos2 = 0;

void setup() {
  servo1.attach (swipservo);
  servo2.attach (liftservo);
  pinMode(leftbutton , INPUT);
  pinMode(rightbutton , INPUT);
}
void loop() {
  test();
}

void test() {
  if (digitalRead(rightbutton) == HIGH) {
    for (pos2 = 0; pos2 < 350; pos2++) {
      if (pos2 < 180) {
        servo2.write (pos2);
        delay(15);
      }
      if (pos1 > 180) {
        servo1.write(0);
        delay(15);
        servo2.write(0);
        delay(15);
      }
      else if (pos2 >= 180) {
        servo1.write(pos1);
        delay(15);
        pos1 ++;
      }
      //go back to 0 for POS 2
    }
  }

  if (digitalRead(leftbutton) == HIGH) {
    for (pos2 = 160; pos2 > 0; pos2++) {
      if (pos2 < 0) {
        servo2.write (pos2);
        delay(5);
      }
      if (pos1 >= 180) {
        servo1.write(0);
        delay(15);
        servo2.write(0);
        delay(15);
      }
      else if (pos2 > 0) {
        servo2.write(pos2);
        delay(15);
      }
      if (pos2 <= 0) {
        servo1.write(pos1);
        delay(15);
        pos1 ++;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In the left button loop it should be `pos—`

Comment: Should I also change the angles of each position indicates first?